# Excel - Do format on row if date above is not the same

Tags: excel

I want to split up a table's row by dates, so it's easier to notice when an event happens on one day. Like this:

[image]

So, I was wondering how to implement this? Maybe like if current row+1 is not the same as current row?

Comment: Please be sure to read the tag descriptions when picking tags for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dark line separators between the sections where the value at cell (row, col) is not the same as the value at (row+1, col), you can use conditional formatting.

I'm using Excel 2010, so your UI might be slightly different.

In the `Home` tab, select `Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules`.

Select `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

In the `Format values where this formula is true` box, type something that looks like `=$A1<>$A2` where A1 and A2 are the first two consecutive cells in the column that you are inspecting.

Click `Format` and in the `Border` tab, select the underscore border and a line style. `OK` your way back out to the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` dialog.

Adjust the `Applies to` range and click `Apply` to check the results. Click `OK` if it looks good.

Comment: It didn't really work: http://puu.sh/67EEa.png  - my Formula: =$L5<>$L6 and yes, it applies to table...

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: From experimenting, it appears as though the first line referenced in the formula must match the first line referenced in the `Applies to` range, so if you have `Applies to` set to `=$A$1:$O$7`, then your formula should be `=$L1<>$L2`, but if your `Applies to` starts on some other row, e.g. `=$A$2:$O$7`, then your formula should start on that row as well, e.g. `=$L2<>$L3`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I get the reasoning behind it, too.